# Adding a delay before calling function in .hover() callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a small delay in the .hover() callback before running further code. I also need to stop the timer if it exists when you hover another elem that triggers the same .hover() func.
I currently have it working but it is not pretty, I'm assigning a timer to a global and sure there must be a better way to do this.

Here is what I have:

```
PACKAGES.activity_icons.hover(function() {

  // If a timer exists kill it here becuase we don't want the 
  // functions in the timer called if we are hovering on another icon
  if(typeof image_restore_timer != 'undefined')
  {
   clearTimeout(image_restore_timer);
  }

  // Only swap image if icon has a class
  if($(this).attr('class') !== '')
  {
   $(this).closest('.package').find('.left_wrap > img').hide();
   // Show the image with the same class as the icon we hovered
   $(this).closest('.package').find('.left_wrap img.'+$(this).attr('class')).show();
  }

 }, function() {

  var this_ref = $(this);

  // Store timer in a global and restore images after a pause
  image_restore_timer = setTimeout(function() {
   (function(el) {
    el.closest('.package').find('.left_wrap img.'+this_ref.attr('class')).hide();
    el.closest('.package').find('.left_wrap > img:eq(0)').fadeIn('slow');
   })(this_ref)
  }, 1000);

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a timer per element (instead of a global one) using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), like this:

```
PACKAGES.activity_icons.hover(function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

  if(this.className === '') return;
  $(this).closest('.package').find('.left_wrap > img').hide()
                       .end().find('.left_wrap img.'+ this.className).show();
}, function() {
  var el = this;
  $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).closest('.package').find('.left_wrap img.' + el.className).hide()
                       .end().find('.left_wrap > img:eq(0)').fadeIn('slow');
  }, 1000));
});
```

The other changes are just some optimizations, the main idea is store the timer using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and clear that same timer.  Also, [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearTimeout) doesn't error with a null or already-run timer, so you can just call it with no check.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into solutions before posting the question and came to the conclusion the hoverIntent plugin wouldn't quite work for what I need to do.